# My new 18650 battery got a little scratch near positive pole

Tags: batteries

So recently I just bought two new batteries. When I took it from the package I accidentaly dropped one of the batteries on the ground and a little scratch appeared near positive pole. It's actually pretty small scratch and i don't know if you can see it in the picture.

What should I do? Is there a posibility to cause a short?[image]

Comment: How could a scratch (that I can't even see on this picture) possibly cause a short?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm new to this thing and i don't want to get hurt just because of some little scratch. And actually it's possible to see the scratch but it's unfocused.

Comment: perhaps take a photo which shows the scratch or at least highlight it so we can tell what you're talking about.

Comment: This is probably the one time I'll ever say this, but lithium batteries aren't _that_ sensitive to damage.

Comment: I did some highlight. By looking at the battery i can see some metal shining through.  I asked my friend about it and he said that everything will be ok.

Comment: You appear to have scuffed a plastic coating.  If you puncture or put a large dent in the can underneath, you'll have a problem.  A small dent probably justifies replacement but will not cause catastrophic failure.

Comment: I would not worry about it at all. HOWEVER, the metal under the scratich is actually directly connected to the negative terminal of the battery. If, somehow, you shorted from the exposed metal under the scratch to the positive terminal, that would be a direct short circuit of the cell. I am not worried about it because that seems most unlikely to happen.

Comment: @KH Thanks for helping, i'll probably will try to cover it up with something just for safety, cause i don't really want to take the risk. And actually i'm really worried about small things.

Comment: OK. But don't make it worse by doing something drastic. ;-)

Comment: @mkeith Thanks for the help! :) You know, I'am just new to these things and I really get worried about something small. :\

Comment: Totally understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no problem using that battery if you have a compatible socket and you make sure no metal touches that area.

Comment: No problem, just make sure nothing bad happens.

Answer (score 0):

How far did you drop it and how hard was the surface? That can be fatal. They usually self-discharge and lose capacity quicker from this but not necessarily get too hot.

e.g. A drop from 1m with a compression stop of 0.1mm is equivalent to 10,000 g's from the ratio of drop to stop distance measured by it's compression unless it compressed more and flexed back. Then guessing maybe 1m/1mm= 1,000 g.

I proved this formula with accelerometers in the 80's when Operating Systems which were distributed on 5.25" hard disk cartridges from 30cm and there was no visible scratch. Yet it was enough to offset the disk and fail to recover data.  Yet the fragility of any object depends on the g vs t fragility boundary curve which is not provided to customers. I resolved the problem with a better sleeve at Syquest.

Batteries have similar small tolerances between edge conductors and this dent is near the edge of the cylinder.  So I would expect degradation but not a safety risk.